# Tkinter dynamically change a widget position with grid geometry manager

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently working on a program where I need to change the position of a widget.
Here is my code:

```
root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root, bg="black")
label1 = Label(frame, text="not important")
label.grid(row=1, column=1)
#some stuff happens
x = aFunctionThatReturnsXCoordinate #not actual name
y = aFunctionThatReturnsYCoordinate
```

Now I want to change the position of `label1` to the new coordinates.
I have tried:

```
label1.forget_grid()
label1.grid(rows=x, columns=y)
#Ive tried label1/frame.update after this code but it didnt do anything
```

I've also tried to do it without the grid_forget.
I didn't forget the `frame.pack` and `root.mainloop`.

Is there a function to change the position?

Comment: Does your code have more widgets in it? I think tkinter collapses empty rows and columns, so your code would be changing the grid position of label1 but this has no effect on the output.

Comment: You've got some obvious typos there (`rows`/`columns` instead of `row`/`column` for example), but that looks like it should work.  In what way does it go wrong?  (You don't need the `grid_forget()`, a widget can only exist in one place so that's done automatically.)

Comment: @jasonharper It just stays on the position it was before. Also the grid has more widgets so its coordinates are in the grid and not outside.

Comment: I assume you've tried printing out `x` and `y`, to make sure they didn't accidentally equal the original row and column?  Otherwise, we need to see a [mcve].

Comment: What you've done is exactly how you do it, except that you don't need to first call `forget_grid` (which doesn't exist), or `grid_forget` (which exists, but unnecessary in this case). You simply need to call the `grid` method on the widget and give it new coordinates.

Comment: I wrote the example a bit differant and it worked so I changed my code and now it kinda works. It jumps to the wrong grid but i think i can fix this myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that toggles the position of a label from column 0 to column 1:

You have to keep in mind that unoccupied rows or columns are sized at zero pixels by the `grid` geometry manager.

pressing the button makes the label in row 1 swap places from column 0 to 1 and vice versa.

```
import tkinter as tk


def move_label(ndx=[0]):

    # the 3 next toggle the column value
    rowcol = [(1, 1), (1, 0)]
    x, y = rowcol[ndx[0]]
    ndx[0] = (ndx[0] + 1) % 2

    label_at_1_0.grid(row=x, column=y)


root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="black")
frame.pack()

label_at_0_0 = tk.Label(frame, text="label_at_0_0")
label_at_0_0.grid(row=0, column=0)

label_at_0_1 = tk.Label(frame, text="not label_at_0_1")
label_at_0_1.grid(row=0, column=1)

label_at_1_0 = tk.Label(frame, text="label_at_1_0")
label_at_1_0.grid(row=1, column=0)

btn_to_move_label = tk.Button(frame, text='move label', command=move_label)
btn_to_move_label.grid(row=1, column=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a code which contains a label and a button. When the button is pressed , the row of the label changes from 0 to 1 and when pressed again row is changes from 1 to 0 and so on. To make difference between the frame and the root, I have set the color of the frame to `sky blue` and that of root to `pink`.

```
from tkinter import *

global rw;rw = 0
def changed():
    global rw;rw += 1;
    if rw == 2:rw=0
    label.grid(row=rw,column=0)
root = Tk()
root.config(bg="pink")
frame = Frame(root, bg="sky blue")
frame.pack()

label = Label(frame,text="Hello")
label.grid(row=0,column=0)
b = Button(frame, text='Press me!', command=changed)
b.grid(row=0, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Well, the above code is a bit complicated so , if you want a simpler way to do the same:

```
from tkinter import *

def changed():
    size = label.grid_info().get("row") #getting current row
    if size == 0:size = 1
    elif size == 1:size = 0
    label.grid(row=size,column=0)
root = Tk()
root.config(bg="pink")
frame = Frame(root, bg="sky blue")
frame.pack()

label = Label(frame,text="Hello")
label.grid(row=0,column=0)
b = Button(frame, text='Press me!', command=changed)
b.grid(row=0, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Here is an animation:
[image: GIPHY]